# Find most distant points in contour curve

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have some `x,y` data for which I obtain a gaussian kernel density estimator (KDE) using the [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) function. I can plot this so as to display the contour density curves shown below the MWE.

Here's the MWE and the resulting plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# Data.
x = [1.81,1.715,1.78,1.613,1.629,1.714,1.62,1.738,1.495,1.669,1.57,1.877,1.385,2.129,2.016,1.606,1.444,2.103,1.397,1.854,1.327,1.377,1.798,1.684,2.186,2.079,1.32,1.452,2.272,1.313,1.762,2.308,2.285,2.328,2.288,2.345,2.237,2.078,2.057,1.505,2.595,2.176,2.501,0.942,2.424,2.49,2.65,1.303,2.43,2.241,0.897,1.731,2.464,1.638,0.867,2.392,3.248,2.608,2.733,0.745,2.715,3.078,2.571,0.771,1.071,2.574,3.343,2.835,2.629,3.421,0.642,2.571,2.698,0.595,2.912,0.563,2.832,2.636,3.149,2.522,0.836,0.894,0.447,1.304,1.132,2.488,3.363,2.961,1.317,2.387,0.036,2.199,0.356,3.036,2.103,2.894,-0.097,0.069,2.688,-0.083,0.653,3.247,3.045,3.197,2.963,2.473,2.571,3.333,3.009,1.281,3.257,3.116,2.673,2.901,2.903,2.634,-0.291,-0.29,0.212]
y = [0.924,0.915,0.914,0.91,0.909,0.905,0.905,0.893,0.886,0.881,0.873,0.873,0.844,0.838,0.83,0.817,0.811,0.809,0.807,0.803,0.802,0.792,0.777,0.774,0.774,0.77,0.748,0.746,0.742,0.734,0.729,0.726,0.722,0.677,0.676,0.672,0.635,0.62,0.62,0.608,0.605,0.587,0.586,0.578,0.571,0.569,0.549,0.544,0.535,0.53,0.529,0.513,0.499,0.497,0.496,0.496,0.49,0.486,0.482,0.476,0.474,0.473,0.471,0.47,0.459,0.444,0.438,0.435,0.428,0.419,0.411,0.4,0.396,0.384,0.378,0.368,0.362,0.362,0.361,0.357,0.347,0.346,0.344,0.33,0.322,0.319,0.318,0.305,0.296,0.296,0.289,0.288,0.288,0.288,0.287,0.286,0.283,0.283,0.278,0.274,0.264,0.259,0.248,0.244,0.241,0.239,0.238,0.237,0.23,0.222,0.221,0.218,0.214,0.212,0.207,0.205,0.196,0.19,0.182]
xmin, xmax = min(x), max(x)
ymin, ymax = min(y), max(y)

# Generate KDE.
x1, y1 = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([x1.ravel(), y1.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
kde = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, x1.shape)

# Make plot.
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(x1,y1,kde)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10, zorder=6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm interested in the *shape* of this output. What I need in particular is a way to obtain the `x,y` coordinates of the **two most distant points** for each *density curve*. For example, for the lower right `0.7` red curve, the coordinates would be around: `(x1,y1)=(2.7,0.42)` and `(x2,y2)=(2.9,0.29)` (points marked as black circles).

This is even more complicated by the fact that there are curves with equal density values (ie: two red curves with a value of `0.7`, two orange curves with `0.6`, etc) so I would need a way to distinguish between these or to leave out certain curves with given values.

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem and any help or direction would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is our solution:**
**Check the processing part...**

```
from __future__ import division
import scipy as sp
from scipy import stats
import pylab as pl

x = [1.81,1.715,1.78,1.613,1.629,1.714,1.62,1.738,1.495,1.669,1.57,1.877,1.385,2.129, \
     2.016,1.606,1.444,2.103,1.397,1.854,1.327,1.377,1.798,1.684,2.186,2.079,1.32, \
     1.452,2.272,1.313,1.762,2.308,2.285,2.328,2.288,2.345,2.237,2.078,2.057,1.505, \
     2.595,2.176,2.501,0.942,2.424,2.49,2.65,1.303,2.43,2.241,0.897,1.731,2.464,1.638, \
     0.867,2.392,3.248,2.608,2.733,0.745,2.715,3.078,2.571,0.771,1.071,2.574,3.343, \
     2.835,2.629,3.421,0.642,2.571,2.698,0.595,2.912,0.563,2.832,2.636,3.149,2.522, \
     0.836,0.894,0.447,1.304,1.132,2.488,3.363,2.961,1.317,2.387,0.036,2.199,0.356, \
     3.036,2.103,2.894,-0.097,0.069,2.688,-0.083,0.653,3.247,3.045,3.197,2.963,2.473, \
     2.571,3.333,3.009,1.281,3.257,3.116,2.673,2.901,2.903,2.634,-0.291,-0.29,0.212]
y = [0.924,0.915,0.914,0.91,0.909,0.905,0.905,0.893,0.886,0.881,0.873,0.873,0.844, \
     0.838,0.83,0.817,0.811,0.809,0.807,0.803,0.802,0.792,0.777,0.774,0.774,0.77,0.748, \
     0.746,0.742,0.734,0.729,0.726,0.722,0.677,0.676,0.672,0.635,0.62,0.62,0.608,0.605, \
     0.587,0.586,0.578,0.571,0.569,0.549,0.544,0.535,0.53,0.529,0.513,0.499,0.497, \
     0.496,0.496,0.49,0.486,0.482,0.476,0.474,0.473,0.471,0.47,0.459,0.444,0.438,0.435, \
     0.428,0.419,0.411,0.4,0.396,0.384,0.378,0.368,0.362,0.362,0.361,0.357,0.347,0.346, \
     0.344,0.33,0.322,0.319,0.318,0.305,0.296,0.296,0.289,0.288,0.288,0.288,0.287, \
     0.286,0.283,0.283,0.278,0.274,0.264,0.259,0.248,0.244,0.241,0.239,0.238,0.237, \
     0.23,0.222,0.221,0.218,0.214,0.212,0.207,0.205,0.196,0.19,0.182]

xmin, xmax = min(x), max(x)
ymin, ymax = min(y), max(y)

# Generate KDE
x1, y1 = sp.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = sp.vstack([x1.ravel(), y1.ravel()])
values = sp.vstack([x, y])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
kde = sp.reshape(kernel(positions).T, x1.shape)

# plotting
CS = pl.contour(x1,y1,kde)

# ----------------------------------- our solution ------------------------------------
# processing the distances
for i,clc in enumerate(CS.collections):
    for j,pth in enumerate(clc.get_paths()):
        cts = pth.vertices
        d = sp.spatial.distance.cdist(cts,cts)
        x,y = cts[list(sp.unravel_index(sp.argmax(d),d.shape))].T
        pl.plot(x,y,':o')
        print 'Contour Level %d, Part %d'%(i,j)
# ----------------------------------- our solution ------------------------------------

pl.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10, zorder=6)
pl.axis('image')                   # don't forget using this to fix aspect ratio to 1,1

pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is such an amazing answer. You did in **five lines** something I didn't even think could be done. Truly amazing, thank you so much @Developer!

Comment: Minor comment: `from __future__ import division` this does not appear to be necessary, am I missing something?

Comment: @Gabriel You're welcome! Yes `from __future...` is not necessary here, however, if you're using `Python 2.xx` and you may develop the above in your main code, it is most likely there will be a `division` somewhere thus putting this at first line of your codes may keep you safe against having unnecessary headache (what's happening!?) later ;)

Comment: Developer: oh so that's where the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py:808: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  z = np.take(y, i0) + (xn-np.take(b,i0))*dy/db` warnings came from after I took out that line? Scratch that, I'm still getting that warning even after adding `from __future...`.